# XHTML syntax validator not visible in Eclipse (in validation menu option under Window->Preferences)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-plugin, xhtml

Currently I have an eclipse installation which runs fine.I have some JSF projects imported on which I am working.

I switched the workspace to work on another JSF project but I observe that there are some differences in the eclipse configuration.

I use to sometimes disable XHTML syntax validator for fastening the workspace.
But in the new workspace I see that this option is missing.

It is seen in the below image:
[image]

But in a different workspace it is not available:

[image: Capture2]

What is the possible configuration which is missing from the second workspace configuration.
And where I can rectify to get this option?